# gxt uibinder TabItem.getHeader().setVisible(false)

Tags: gwt, gxt, uibinder, tabpanel

Can I set widget's property's property in *.ui.xml? For example, gxt:TabItem header.visible="false" ?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe GXT have caught up to GWT in regards to this however there is an open source project working on this.

[GXT-UIBinder](http://code.google.com/p/gxt-uibinder/)